# Splitting strings in complicated ways?

Tags: python, string, split

I'm making a basic language. Well, not exactly, but you'll see. Now, I did echo and exit commands, but I need help.

If I give it a string 'echo "hello bob"' I want it to split it up, and give me an array like so [echo, Hello Bob]. Now, I have echo working, but with only ONE word. So I can do --> 'echo bob', and it will output 'bob'. But, If I do 'echo hi bob' it will output 'hi'. And I always want it to do that. If I have a command foo, I want to do 'foo "bar face" boo' and get [foo, bar face, boo]. So basically I want to do myArr.split(' ') except for anything in between quotes. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe the `parser` module can do this, although I've never used it.

Comment: Sorry not the `parser` module, the `shlex` module, it provides a way to parse shell-like languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple answer:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('echo "hello bob"')
['echo', 'hello bob']
```

`shlex` is a module that helps with parsing shell-like languages.

The documentation can be found here (thank you, JIStone): http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple tokenizer

```
import re

def s_ident(scanner, token): return token
def s_operator(scanner, token): return "op%s" % token
def s_float(scanner, token): return float(token)
def s_int(scanner, token): return int(token)

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"[a-zA-Z_]\w*", s_ident),
    (r"\d+\.\d*", s_float),
    (r"\d+", s_int),
    (r"=|\+|-|\*|/", s_operator),
    (r"\s+", None),
    ])

print scanner.scan("sum = 3*foo + 312.50 + bar")
```

You will need a parser to actually use this lex'd content